# Copy Data from One Sheet to Another Sheet by Matching Column Names

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two sheets in my Workbook. Both have same columns but in different order. I need to copy all the rows from one sheet to another.

Any way to copy the data exactly under matching column names ? Both sheets have columns upto CZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do VB Editor Menu/Tools/References and check the box next to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
That gives you access to Scripting.Dictionary, which is a keyed hash object (key/value pairs)

```
Sub CopyByCol()

Dim lCol As Long, lCols As Long, sCol As String, lRows As Long
Dim dictCol As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rFrom As Range, rTo As Range

    Set rFrom = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set rTo = Sheet2.Range("A1")

' Store hash of where column names occur in target sheet, keyed by Col name
    lCols = rFrom.Offset(0, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column - rFrom.Column
    For lCol = 0 To lCols
        sCol = rTo.Offset(0, lCol).Value
        dictCol.Add sCol, lCol
    Next

' Get key column name from From sheet, and write to correct col in To sheet
    For lCol = 0 To lCols
        sCol = rFrom.Offset(0, lCol).Value
        lRows = rFrom.Offset(65000, lCol).End(xlUp).Row - rFrom.Row
        Range(rFrom.Offset(1, lCol), rFrom.Offset(lRows, lCol)).Copy Destination:=rTo.Offset(1, dictCol(sCol))
    Next

End Sub
```